# Installing phpmyadmin on php7 : Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have LAMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have upgraded from php 5.0 to php 7.0 but i couldn't install `phpmyadmin`.

I went to my public folder which is `var/www/domain.com/html` and ran that code,

`git clone --depth=1 --branch=STABLE https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git`

It looks like it is installed i see the folder in html directory but when i check `domain.com/phpmyadmin` it gives nothing.

what am i missing?

Comment: Did you update with composer?

Comment: no 
i just used naked code.which is perfectly working but something is missing

Comment: Is there any reason why you used the git version than using the Ubuntu repository ?

Comment: i am new to server management so before using git version i followed [this tutorial on digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) but this is 2 years old and this available for php 5.0 

i dont know how to get latest version of phpmyadmin via ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully installed phpMyadmin on ubuntu 14.04 with php7 using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Note: this solution was tested witn Apache web server.

Comment: I'm getting "couldnt add the PPA" please check de PPA.

Comment: ... Michal Čihař, admin and main contributor of this project resigned last month.

Comment: this does not work for ubuntu 14 has not support anymore. Take this into account.